# ToDo List Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, todo

I am making an application in Swift language with UIKIT
the application is as follows
ToDo List in which I need to output tasks as follows 1 there should be only two sections
completed with the button marked and unfulfilled now I have reached the point that I have each new ToDo created in a new section. What to do?
Here is my code and what I got
as a datasource I have an array inside an array

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    private var arrExecuteToDo = [String]()
    private var todos = [[ToDoItem]]()
    private var selectedIndex: Int?   // global var for the operation of the row index in the extension
    private var todoStatus: [ToDoStatus] = [.completed, .planed]
    
    enum Constants {
        static let addTaskIndentifier: String = "addTaskVc"
        static let cellIndentifier: String = "ToDoCell"
        static let mainStoryboard: String = "Main"
        static let secondVC: String = "secondVC"
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
        
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == Constants.addTaskIndentifier {
            let addTaskVC = segue.destination as? AddTaskViewController // create a link to the second view controller
            addTaskVC?.type = .create
            addTaskVC?.delegate = self // subscribe it to the delegate of the second controller
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view Data Source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        todos[section].count
    }
    
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        todos.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.cellIndentifier,
                                                       for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }  // cast on your cell
        _ = todos[indexPath.row] // pick up the current body by cell index
        let todo = todos[indexPath.section]
        cell.configureCell(with: todo[indexPath.row]) // config a cell from a cell
        return cell
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let secondeVC = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.mainStoryboard, bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: Constants.secondVC) as? AddTaskViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to Instantiate Quotes View Controller")
        }
        
        let todoSection = todos[indexPath.section]
        
        _ = secondeVC.view
        secondeVC.configure(with: todoSection[indexPath.row])
        secondeVC.type = .edit
        secondeVC.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondeVC, animated: true)
        
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { // swipe deleted todo
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete) {
            todos.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions
extension TableViewController: AddTaskVCDelegate {
    // here we get data from the second view
    func didCreateToDo(todo: ToDoItem) {
        todos.append([todo]) // add a new element to the array
        tableView.reloadData() // reload the table
    }
    
    func didUpdateToDo(todo: ToDoItem) {
        guard let index = selectedIndex else { return }
        todos[index] = [todo]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func didDeleteToDo() { // add protocol method for delete todo
        guard let index = selectedIndex else { return }
        todos.remove(at: index)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
}
```

I thought that the problem is how I display the sections of the table, but I did not find how to change it as I need it

Answer (score 0):

Because you create a separate section for each task in your code, a new section is created for each new ToDo. You say you only need two parts: "Completed" and "Uncompleted". To fix this situation, you need to use a separate array for both parts.

Here are the steps you need to do:

1-) Define the todos array as a single array of type [ToDoItem]. This series will include completed and unfinished tasks.

```
private var todos = [ToDoItem]()
```

2-) Remove the todoStatus array because it will no longer be associated with any partition.

```
private var todoStatus: [ToDoStatus] = [.completed, .planned]
```

3-) Let the numberOfSections function return 2 as a constant. This value can remain constant as there will always be only two partitions.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 2
```

}

4-) Update the tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) function. Filter the todos array accordingly to return the number of tasks in each section.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if section == 0 { 
    return todos.filter { $0.status == .completed }.count
} else { 
    return todos.filter { $0.status == .planned }.count
}
```

}

5-) Update the cellForRowAt function. Based on the section number and line number, get the corresponding ToDo and configure the cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.cellIndentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

let todo: ToDoItem
if indexPath.section == 0 { 
    let completedTodos = todos.filter { $0.status == .completed }
    todo = completedTodos[indexPath.row]
} else { 
    let plannedTodos = todos.filter { $0.status == .planned }
    todo = plannedTodos[indexPath.row]
}

cell.configureCell(with: todo)
return cell
```

}

With these changes, you will keep all the ToDo items within the todos array and filter the related tasks in each section.

Comment: if I delete private var todoStatus: [ToDoStatus] = [.completed, .planned]  where do I get completed, .planned from ?

Comment: If you remove the todoStatus array, you can define the ToDoStatus cases (completed and planned) directly within your code. You don't need to retrieve them from another source. Here's an example of how you can define the ToDoStatus enum without relying on the todoStatus array

`enum ToDoStatus {
    case completed
    case planned
}`

Comment: With this modification, you can use the ToDoStatus.completed and ToDoStatus.planned cases directly in your code. For instance, when creating a new ToDoItem, you can set its status as follows:

`let completedTodo = ToDoItem(title: "Completed Task", status: .completed)`

Comment: I still don't understand
, I do as you say, and I still get the error that the compiler doesn't understand where to take it from